# Можно ли в Python нарушить инкапсуляцию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, инкапсуляция

Вот код:

```
class mutant():

    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def method_(self):
        print(f'i am good&print a={self.a}')

def method_(self):
    print(f'i am MUTANT&print b={self.b}')

z = mutant(3,500)
z.method_()
z.__dict__['method_'] = method_    
z.method_()
```

ясное дело не работает. 
можно ли как-то его сделать таким, чтобы на выходе было:

```
i am good&print a=3
i am MUTANT&print b=500
```

Помнится где-то читал что в Python инкапсуляция "ненастоящая", а примера найти не могу. Сможем?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Отличие только в типе `method` vs `function`. Значит, проще всего обернуть:

```
from types import MethodType

...

z = mutant(3,500)
method_ = MethodType(method_, z)

z.method_()  # i am good&print a=3
z.__dict__['method_'] = method_    
z.method_()  # i am MUTANT&print b=500
```

Answer (score 8):

Важное примечание: ни один из способов (даже `MethodType` из соседнего ответа) не даст доступа к приватным атрибутам, начинающимся с двух подчёркиваний (`self.__c`). Нужно будет использовать что-то вроде `self._mutant__c`, как и в других аналогичных случаях.

---

Вариант номер раз, без `self` (функции и так известен объект через переменную `z`):

```
class mutant():
    ...

def method_():
    print(f'i am MUTANT&print b={z.b}')

z = mutant(3,500)
z.method_()
z.method_ = method_    
z.method_()
```

Вариант номер два, если очень хочется `self`:

```
import functools

class mutant():
    ...

def method_(self):
    print(f'i am MUTANT&print b={self.b}')

z = mutant(3,500)
z.method_()
z.method_ = functools.partial(method_, z)    
z.method_()
```

Вариант номер три, с изменением класса, а не экземпляра:

```
class mutant():
    ...

def method_(self):
    print(f'i am MUTANT&print b={self.b}')

z = mutant(3,500)
z.method_()
mutant.method_ = method_    
z.method_()
```

Вариант номер четыре — [MethodType](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/909104)